A story with a TVTropes page where there's a difference between regular mined and smelted gold vs. magic / (System-made?) gold
A probably-LitRPG story with a TVTropes page where there's a difference between regular mined and smelted gold vs. magic / (System-made?) / Dungeon gold.
People know about it and it's easily detectable, and an important part of the economy, maybe?
It's a measure to prevent the devaluation of gold, or to solve some other economic problem were (quite sure it's Dungeon-made) gold to be undifferentiable from other gold.
The TVTropes pages, CheapGoldCoins, LitRPG, Dungeon-Based Economy and Artistic License - Economics aren't helping, or at least their Literature folders aren't.

I don't know if it is the book you're looking for, but the Generica Online books by Andrew Seiple, including the Threadbare, Small Medium, and Blasphemy Online series, have a "Fool's Gold" skill granted to the Grifter class (and some Cultists) that lets them summon temporary fake gold that is only distinguishable via the aura of magic. Offhand, it was plot-relevant in the second book of Small Medium, where Thomassi reflexively passes it to an organized crime affiliate, resulting in him getting impressed into service (and he later uses it to cheat someone regarding Player tokens in the same book), and around the second or third book of the Blasphemy Online where a group of villagers who've become Cultists of Anjuuta learn to summon fake gold, and wind up killing the local tax collector after he catches on to the fakes, resulting in some minor drama.

Thanks, but since I read all of the series, this wouldn't be it unless I got very forgetful. The Magic-touched gold is a known and used part of the economy by all people, I think.
